# Swift - Segue from UIViewController within NavigationController to UIViewController within TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app, things start off with a registration flow, including profile creation, mobile verification, and some further customization which all happens inside separate `UIViewControllers` managed by a `UINavigationController`.

However, when registration is completed, I want to leave the `UINavigationController` and have my final registration View Controller segue to the main `TabBarController` of the application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a navigation controller that controls more than one UIViewController, you use push *push* segues. When you want to leave that navigation controller, you will have to use a *modal* segue. I'm assuming that you are using the Storyboard. When you click and drag from one UIViewController to the next, you choose modal instead of push.

Answer (score 0):

Segues are useful for prototyping, but for a real app I would avoid using segues and control the display of view controllers programmatically.

In your case, you could make the TabBarController the main entry point, and then detect whether the user has registered, and if not, display the registration sequence (modally) on top of this, and when the user completes the sequence, just dismiss it and you'll be back to TabBarController.

Or you could make your initial view controller a blank screen which then decides whether to display the registration sequence or the TabBarController.